# Does OpenZeppelin make security audits?

Tags: openzeppelin

Does the [OpenZeppelin](https://openzeppelin.org/) project offer security audit services for other projects and companies?

Comment: I don't think this is customer support, it's precisely the opposite. We want people to understand that OpenZeppelin is free for everybody to use, and that there's an ecosystem of companies that can offer services, not just the one that started OpenZeppelin. This is the most common misconception when people want to use OpenZeppelin. We are not trying to sell our services on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

No, OpenZeppelin doesn't make security audits. OpenZeppelin is a community project that builds a framework of reusable smart contracts. The project doesn't offer any auditing services for things not related to the development this framework.

The confusion arises because OpenZeppelin was started by the [Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.solutions/) company. Zeppelin is the main supporter of the project and most of the OpenZeppelin maintainers are also Zeppelin employees. [Zeppelin offers audit services](https://zeppelin.solutions/security-audits/), but as a complete separate branch from the work they do to support the OpenZeppelin framework.

OpenZeppelin has contributions from many different companies and individuals, some of which also provide auditing services. The [OpenZeppelin slack](https://slack.openzeppelin.org/) has a [#jobs channel](https://openzeppelin.slack.com/messages/C79QL6CSY) where people can get in contact with members of this community that provide these auditing services.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing :)
We have renamed the company from Zeppelin to OpenZeppelin, so now the answer should be yes, OpenZeppelin makes security audits.
Now I would have to agree that this could be seen as customer support, and off-topic. Sorry about that.
More info about the rename: https://blog.openzeppelin.com/openzeppelin-rebranding/